# Android bluetooth friendly name

Tags: android, bluetooth

How can i retrieve the device name (not friendly name) of the BT discovered device using Android API's?

Answer (score 0):

After the `socket.connect` and `socket.accept` is been done.. ie BT connection established..
You will be having the socket.. Try this..

```
 socket.getRemoteDevice().getName();
 socket.getRemoteDevice().getAddress();
```

from this you can get the name of the remote device which you are connected with.